# Xml file generation

Tags: java, xml, oracle-adf

I want to generate the XML file in below format.

```
'<root>
<row serialno="1234"/>
<row serialno="12345"/>
</root>'
```

I am able to generate the XML file in below format.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<root>
<serialno>1</serialno>
<serialno>2</serialno>
<serialno>3</serialno>
<serialno>4</serialno>
</root>
```

Code written for generating a XML file in java :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateXmlFileDemo createXmlFileDemo = new CreateXmlFileDemo();
        XmlType reqInXml;
        XmlType reqOutXML;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
//            Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
            // root element
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("root");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            // staff elements
//            Element row = doc.createElement("row");
//            rootElement.appendChild(row);


            // firstname elements
            for(int i=1; i<5;i++){
                String strI = "serialno";
                String testValue = Integer.toString(i);
                Element serialno = doc.createElement(strI);    
                serialno.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(testValue));
                sb.append(serialno);
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                rootElement.appendChild(serialno);
            }


            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); 
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
            serializer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(stw));
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("D:\\Files.xml"));
            System.out.println(stw.toString());
            // Output to console for testing
            // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

            transformer.transform(source, result);
            System.out.println("File saved!");

        }catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    }
        catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
}
```

Can any 1 help me to generate the XML file as mention in the format below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this piece of code

```
// firstname elements
        for(int i=1; i<5;i++){ 
            Element row= doc.createElement("row");    
            row.setAttribute("serialno",Integer.toString(i));
            rootElement.appendChild(row);
        }
```